# An animation within an animation

Tags: animation, constraints

I've created a pendulum rotating around a circle with a Follow Path constraint. I would like this animated pendulum to follow a curve in my scene, but as soon as I constraint my pendulum to this curve with a Follow Path, the pendulum goes completely crazy (because the position of the bone following the circle is relative to the center of the scene).

How can I fix this and make my animated pendulum follow my curve? In other words, how can I create a Follow Path animation within another Follow Path animation, and if it's not possible what is the right way to create a animated object like this pendulum following a path?

blend file:

[image]

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd see two potential ways:

1. use an intermediate empty, plus parenting and constraints, which is a little finnicky to set up, or
2. use a group instance

### Method 1

[image]

The idea is to use an empty, and first parent the circle (your already working path) to it. Then add a `child of` constraint to the main bone of your armature, and make sure to click `set inverse` right after that. Now both the armature and the curve follow the empty. move the empty to the scene origin, and the second curve as well. Use the `follow path` constraint on the empty to target the second curve and set the parameters as you like.

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

### Method 2

[image]

Select every **object** which the pendulum is made of - that includes the armature object and the curve - and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to create a group around it. Name it appropriately (I chose Pendulum). Make sure to also use the `Offset from Cursor` function like in the GIF. Basically, this allows you to define the Origin Point of the instance relative to the current cursor position. Then, use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and add a group instance of Pendulum to the scene. Use the follow path constraint on this new instance.

[image: group instance]

Personally, I find method number 2 far less convoluted and error-prone, but what fits your situation best is up to you.